# how to make ArcGis(4.18) map offline and to consume it in angular application

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime

how to make ArcGis(4.18) map offline and to consume it in angular application
tried deploying arc-gis JavaScript API and SDK
and replaced url"https://js.arcgis.com/" with "http://127.0.0.1/arcgis_js_api/library/"
still not working

Answer (score 0):

The download api comes with a test page, did you try it and work fine?